# Global function automatically increase thread numbers or not

Tags: arrays, cuda

In global function do we need to increase threadIndex by using  ix+=1;  iy+=1;
Or Is cuda global function doing this?

My **global** function is:

```
         `__device__ float gpuFrameResultArray[MEMORYFRAME][HEIGHT][WIDTH];

          __global__ void GrayVideoToArrays(float frameReading[HEIGHT][WIDTH],
                              float frameResultArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH],
                              int initialframeCount){

           int ix=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
           int iy=threadIdx.y+blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
           while ( ix < HEIGHT && iy < WIDTH) {

           
           gpuFrameResultArray[initialframeCount][ix][iy] = frameReading[ix][iy] 
        
          
           frameResultArray[ix][iy] = gpuFrameResultArray[initialframeCount][ix][iy] ;
           
           __syncthreads();//sadece blok bazında synchronize  yaparr.

           ix+=1;
           iy+=1;
     }
```

}

Comment: Change the `while` to an `if` and you are done

Answer (score 1):

> Or Is cuda global function doing this?

TL;DR: No, a cuda global function doesn't do that.

Longer:

I usually try to encourage folks to trust their instincts as a C++ programmer.  What we have here:

```
       while ( ix < HEIGHT && iy < WIDTH) {

       
       gpuFrameResultArray[initialframeCount][ix][iy] = frameReading[ix][iy] 
    
      
       frameResultArray[ix][iy] = gpuFrameResultArray[initialframeCount][ix][iy] ;
       
       __syncthreads();//sadece blok bazında synchronize  yaparr.

       ix+=1;
       iy+=1;
 }
```

is entirely C++ code, and CUDA [claims](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) compliance to C++ with some stated restrictions and limitations.

Does C++ automatically increase variables for you?  It does not.  If you want to increase both `ix` and `iy` at each loop iteration, you need to write the code just as you have written it.

Aside:

I'm a bit skeptical that the increment strategy you have:

```
       ix+=1;
       iy+=1;
```

makes any sense (unless your threadblocks consist of only 1 thread).  You're going to create an "odd" diagonal striping pattern through your datasets that way.  The usual strategy here would be a [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) which can be constructed using either a for-loop or a while-loop, and can be constructed in 2 dimensions. (In 2 dimensions, you would typically use 2 loop nests.  You would not increment both the horizontal and vertical strides at the same point.) However the increments in that case would be a grid-stride, not 1.

Aside2:

Different CUDA threads will have different values assigned to these variables:

```
       int ix=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
       int iy=threadIdx.y+blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
```

That is a basic CUDA concept.  However those variables (`ix`, `iy`) for a given thread will not be automatically changed during the lifetime of that thread.  Of course, they are like other C++ variables: you can change them explicitly in your code, if you wish to, as you have done here.